# Display Data Based on Date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jstl, resultset

I have 2 columns in a table in mysql which looks sometime like below,

```
 title    timestamp
--------------------
 test1     1/7/2012
 test2     1/7/2012
 test3     1/7/2012
 test4     2/7/2012
 test5     3/7/2012.
```

The result I am looking for is something like,

```
**1/7/2012**
   test1
   test3
**2/7/2012**
   test4
 **3/7/2012**
   test5
```

Can someone help him here.can this be done just with MySQL query or I need to iterate the resultset in server side and then format the resultset for displaying.

Comment: that's a display issue, and doesn't really have anything to do with the query mechanics. so yes, iterate the result set and format the result

Comment: Thanks Marc,I am working on server side code to get this up.Just wanted to make sure that I was working in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this one:

```
select title,timestamp,str_to_date(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y') as date from table_name order by date,title;
```

iterating over the result set and printing the timestamp only when it changes.

str_to_date is a MySQL function which converts a string to a date, useful for sorting. If you are not using MySQL, you should check for an analogous function.

Comment: I feel its not about sorting or formating, I am getting the data with timestamp desc already and yes I do format date in my server side code after getting resultset,All I need to do is display all the titles for that date and then move to next date, display all titles for that date and so on.

Comment: I think I still need some help.I am not able to go beyond fetching the resultset from the database.Can someone some thoughts as how I should proceed from server side code.I am using java.Appreciate some high level guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want, the code should look like this:

```
int itemsInPage = 100; //Number of item to display in page
int currentPage = 1; //Index of current page, starting from 1

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select title,timestamp,str_to_date(timestamp,'%d/%m/%Y') as date from table_name order by date,title limit " + ((currentPage - 1) * itemsInPage) + ", " + itemsInPage);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

String prevTimestamp = null;

while(rs.next()) {
    if (prevTimestamp == null || !prevTimestamp.equals(rs.getString(2))) {
        System.out.println("*** "+rs.getString(1)+" ***");
    }
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    prevTimestamp = rs.getString(2);
}
```

If you are coding in a jsp, you should use

```
out.print(...);
```

instead of

```
System.out.println
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you on this.I have thousands  of Rows of data which I need to pull out and format it in above pattern and if records exceeds 100, I need to do pagination based on this pattern.Yes I do use JSP but I dont do any Data access in JSP,its just a view, I have model/servlets which does the DB calls and then writes the data in request scope.But I think I see what you are trying to convey.

Comment: No its not working.Do you think Cursors can help here.Get the value of first row of timestamp COLUMN, store in variable a, move the cursor to next row of timestamp, get the value and store it variable b.Compare a and b, if they are same, keep looping till they not equal.If they are equal, stop the loop and write all titles between start row and end row.Any ideas how this can done via JDBC

Comment: If you want to paginate the result set you can use the sql LIMIT statement: http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/UseLIMITinSELECT.htm I edited the code to add a limit statement to the query.